# Java - JDBC Driver SQLite 3.7.2 - Unable to open database test.db: file is encrypted or is not a database

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I'm writing some data to a database file using the SQLite JDBC driver 3.7.2 from within java . When I try it to open the database file on the command line, I get an error message saying:

"Unable to open database test.db: file is encrypted or is not a database"

I made a minimal example that results in this behavior:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class PlaygroundSQLite {
    public static void insertIntoDB(String dbFilename, String tablename){
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+dbFilename);
            PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement("insert into " + tablename + "( id, text) values (?, ?);");

            prep.setString(1, "1FD22A38");
            prep.setString(2, "This is a simple test");

            prep.addBatch();

            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            prep.executeBatch();
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);

            conn.close();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void createDB(String dbFilename, String tablename){
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + dbFilename);
            Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
            stat.executeUpdate("drop table if exists test;");
            stat.executeUpdate("create table " + tablename + " (key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, id TEXT , text TEXT);");
            conn.close();
            stat.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dbFilename = "test.db";
        String tablename = "test";

        PlaygroundSQLite.createDB(dbFilename, tablename);
        PlaygroundSQLite.insertIntoDB(dbFilename, tablename);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem here was a version mismatch between the Java SQLite JDBC Driver (version 3.7.2) and the SQLite version installed on my machine (version 2.8.17). Using a sqlite3 binary solved the problem. I searched for the solution quite a while, so I thought I post it here to make it easier to find the solution for people who are using Java (as I found it in some Java unrelated post).

Comment: Then answer your own question instead of posting a comment :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately though I have to wait 8 hours, as I do not have enough reputation points yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here was a version mismatch between the Java SQLite JDBC Driver (version 3.7.2) and the SQLite version installed on my machine (version 2.8.17). Using a sqlite3 binary solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is there such a thing as: "SQLite JDBC driver 3.7.2 from within java"? I know about JavaDB (Derby) but did not know that there is actually a SQLite JDBC driver inside Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("journal_mode", "WAL");
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+dbFilename,config);
```

Comment: Please try adding some explanation to your answer, why this code solves the problem and what exactly is the important change compared to the question's code.