# Unable to read database(Access 2013) from assets (file is encrypted or is not a database)

Tags: android, sql, database, ms-access-2013

I read some info from here:

[Java - JDBC Driver SQLite 3.7.2 - Unable to open database test.db: file is encrypted or is not a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803140/java-jdbc-driver-sqlite-3-7-2-unable-to-open-database-test-db-file-is-encry)

and no idea about "version mismatch" sqlite3 binary and if it is same problem with `Access`, how can I solve it.

Anyway, I show a part of my code below, as I said before I don't know if it is the same problem:

I created an external database without encryption with `Access 2013`.
My file is less than 1MB and is copy well on DDMS on `"/data/data/" + getPackageName() +"/databases/"`.

When I downloaded from DDMS to my computer I can see all my data (open with Access 2013) so I think is not corrupted.

My problem is when is called `db.getBeers()` on my activity  with

```
    public void GetBeers(){
    db.openDataBase();  
    Cursor c= db.getBeers();
    db.close();
```

On my class `DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper`

```
public Cursor getBeers(){
    return myDataBase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_VOLUMENFERMENTACION,KEY_AZUCAR,KEY_AGUA,              KEY_DINICIAL,KEY_AZUCARBOTELLA,KEY_AZUCARBARRIL,KEY_CATEGORIA},null,null,null,null,null);       
}
```

First error on my logcat:

> E/SQLiteLog(5852): (26) file is encrypted or is not a database.

I hope to see some light on this, it took me hours and i've no idea what's wrong, so any help is welcome.

Comment: Since when can Access create/use sqlite db files?  Just because they're both databases doesn't mean you can magically share the raw data files between the two systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never heard that Access is an option for android platform.
It is maybe a Java only but if you want really a good offline database.

Why you don't use **SQLite**? It's a built in database in Android, you can easily connect to it and do all you want. Since you are seeking to use an offline database it's the best choice, trust me.

Here is a reference :

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Answer (score 1):

> I created an external database without encryption with Access 2013

SQLite has no ability to read Microsoft Access databases.

> E/SQLiteLog(5852): (26) file is encrypted or is not a database.

From SQLite's standpoint, your file is not a database.

> how can I solve it.

Do not attempt to use an Access 2013 database with SQLite. If you wish to package a database with your app, and you wish to use Android's SQLite classes with that database, you need to create a SQLite database.