# Connect to SQlite (Spiceworks) database from ireports (Jaspersoft)

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jdbc, spiceworks

I'm trying to connect to SQLite db from Jaspersoft ireports. I was able to create a datasource successfully but when I create a report using the datasource it gives me below error message.

`java.sql.SQLException: file is encrypted or is not a database`

I'm using below JDBC drivers:

```
JDBC Driver: org.sqlite.JDBC
JDBC URL: jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\sqllitejdbc\\spiceworks_prod.sqlite
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to connect to that database another way than JDBC?

Comment: @GustavoStraube- I was able to open the db from DB Browser for SQLite. It's just when I try to create a report in jaspersoft it gives me an error message.

Comment: Perhaps it's a version problem. Can you confirm that your database was created using SQLite 3?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803140/java-jdbc-driver-sqlite-3-7-2-unable-to-open-database-test-db-file-is-encry

Comment: @Gustavo Straube- Here is the sqlite version: SELECT sqlite_version(); gave me this SQlite version: 3.8.10.2. And   PRAGMA compile_options listed this: ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA; ENABLE_FTS3; ENABLE_FTS4; ENABLE_RTREE; SYSTEM_MALLOC; THREADSAFE=1;

Comment: @Exocom- Any inputs/suggestions on this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure you already did this, but searching the web I found some cases where the database file was corrupted. Do you think it could be your case? Sorry for don't have any useful suggestion now.

Comment: Forget my last comment about the file corruption. You've already said that you can access from DB Browser.

Answer (score 0):

JDBC Driver: org.sqlite.JDBC
JDBC URL: jdbc:sqlite:C:\Users\IT\Desktop\sqllitejdbc\wwe.sqlite

this is how i gave the Driver and URL but it does not work before that i gave jre file(sqlitejdbc-v056) to the classpath